# First time access the windows folder from code

Tags: .net, windows, temp

Currently I'm writing an app that should access a file in `C:\Windows\Temp` folder.
The file is not found when I try to get access from my code.

When I try to open the folder in Windows Explorer I receive a message. The message says:

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder click continue to permanently get access to this folder.

The problem disappears after clicking `Continue` and I can access the file from my code without of any troubles.

Is it possible to achieve the same result from code? Or maybe there is a better place to store  temporary files shared among users.

Motivation to have a shared among users folder:

I have the following workflow:

1. create a DB backup and store it in temp folder
2. do some stuff with the DB
3. restore DB from the file stored in temp folder

Step 1 and 3 are performed by the DB itself, and step 2 by my program. Normally, my program is launched by another user than the DB. That is why I need a folder shared among the users.

Comment: "temporary files shared among users": this sounds like a really bad idea, since temporary files can be deleted anytime... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Usually a database is much more suitable to give shared access to data.

Comment: The temp folder is **NOT** guaranteed to be `c:\windows\temp`. Its location can change by setting an environment variable. Actually, each user has his own temp folder inside his/her profile folder.

Comment: @Panagiotis, I know. That  is why I use the following code:       
`var directory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);`

Comment: That's what the APPDATA folders are for. TEMP is for storing temporary data only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a bad idea, discouraged since Windows 95. Applications and common users are *not* allowed to tinker with the Windows folder for obvious reasons.

Windows provides specific folders for storing application data, either per user or common to all users of an application. They are defined in the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration. You can retrieve the actual values using [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.GetFolderPath.aspx).

Using this method is the only way to get the correct path location, as the location of the folders can change through environment variables, system policies or user preferences.

To get the per-user application data folder, use :

```
var userDataPath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

To get the app dat path common to all users, use:

```
var dataPath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Make sure you create a folder for your application under these folders to avoid destroying data used by other applications

Comment: Programs do *not* have write access to CommonApplicationData folders.

Comment: @Hans This addresses the issue I think http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData

Comment: @HansPassant: they do have the ability to create new common folders, though, and can set any permissions on those folders they wish.  So in practice this will work, provided you set the permissions appropriately.